# React Sequential Rendering Hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I've got some components which need to render sequentially once they've loaded or marked themselves as ready for whatever reason.

In a typical `{things.map(thing => <Thing {...thing} />}` example, they all render at the same time, but I want to render them one by one I created a hook to to provide a list which only contains the sequentially ready items to render.

The problem I'm having is that the children need a function in order to tell the hook when to add the next one into its ready to render state. This function ends up getting changed each time and as such causes an infinite number of re-renders on the child components.

In the examples below, the child component `useEffect` must rely on the dependency `done` to pass the linter rules- if i remove this it works as expected because done isn't a concern whenever it changes but obviously that doesn't solve the issue.

Similarly I could  add `if (!attachment.__loaded) {` into the child component but then the API is poor for the hook if the children need specific implementation such as this.

I think what I need is a way to stop the function being recreated each time but I've not worked out how to do this.

[Codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-river-cs28d?expanddevtools=1&fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

useSequentialRenderer.js

```
import { useReducer, useEffect } from "react";

const loadedProperty = "__loaded";

const reducer = (state, {i, type}) => {
  switch (type) {
    case "ready":
      const copy = [...state];
      copy[i][loadedProperty] = true;
      return copy;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

const defaults = {};

export const useSequentialRenderer = (input, options = defaults) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(options.reducer || reducer, input);

  const index = state.findIndex(a => !a[loadedProperty]);
  const sliced = index < 0 ? state.slice() : state.slice(0, index + 1);

  const items = sliced.map((item, i) => {
    function done() {
      dispatch({ type: "ready", i });
      return i; 
    }

    return { ...item, done };
  });

  return { items };
};
```

example.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { useSequentialRenderer } from "./useSequentialRenderer";

const Attachment = ({ children, done }) => {
  const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const delay = Math.random() * 3000;

    const timer = setTimeout(() => {
      setLoaded(true);
      const i = done();
      console.log("happening multiple times", i, new Date());
    }, delay);

    return () => clearTimeout(timer);
  }, [done]);

  return <div>{loaded ? children : "loading"}</div>;
};

const Attachments = props => {
  const { items } = useSequentialRenderer(props.children);

  return (
    <>
      {items.map((attachment, i) => {
        return (
          <Attachment key={attachment.text} done={() => attachment.done()}>
            {attachment.text}
          </Attachment>
        );
      })}
    </>
  );
};

function App() {
  const attachments = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8].map(a => ({
    loaded: false,
    text: a
  }));

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Attachments>{attachments}</Attachments>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap your callback in an aditional layer of dependency check with `useCallback`. This will ensure a stable identity across renders

```
const Component = ({ callback }) =>{
    const stableCb = useCallback(callback, [])

    useEffect(() =>{
        stableCb()
    },[stableCb])
}
```

Notice that if the signature needs to change you should declare the dependencies as well

```
const Component = ({ cb, deps }) =>{
    const stableCb = useCallback(cb, [deps])
    /*...*/
}
```

[image: Edit vigorous-beaver-h2es6]

Comment: Wow, nice answer

Comment: Thanks very much. This does indeed work. Is there a way that I can apply this without needing to do it inside the child component? I.e. pull this complexity into the hook somehow to hide it away from the consumer?

Comment: But I can't use `useCallback` inside a loop so I don't know how many callbacks I need to make

Comment: Actually this is supposed to be done inside your custom hook.

Comment: I'll take a look at your sandbox. 1 sec

Comment: Well. It's running multiple times cause there are multiple instances. Your goal is to call `done` only once? The current sandbox is calling once per `Attachment`

Comment: Watch the console on the sandbox. It infinitely runs the setTimeouts for all the different Attachment components

Comment: Apologies you might have been seeing it with your useCallback fix in Attachment applied. I'd not forked it when i tried your answer. Try now

Comment: oh! I see. Ok, I'm on it

Comment: Ok. I think I came up with a solution. After lunch I'll update the sandbox

Comment: Thanks very much. This applies the complexity inside the child component. Whilst this works and got me one step further, I'm trying to find a way to bring this complexity into the hook as opposed to the child component (Attachment) in this case. Adding it to the Attachment isn't a nice or memorable API, and as there are lots of different attachment types it'd be easy to forget and there'd be lots of duplication. I assume there must be a way I can stabilise the callback in the hook somehow so it doesn't constantly change those passed to the child components. Any thoughts in that regard?

Comment: The problem is that what is triggering the loop. Think about it: Inside attachment you receive a function as prop and change the state, triggering a call to that component thus creating another function. What is triggering the loop isn't your hook, is the effect inside attachment.

Comment: The complexity must lie inside `Attachment` since it is the problem. You could create a generic wrapper which memoize (`React.memo`) the component to avoid unecessary renders. But sadly there is nothing you can change in your hook that would prevent this from happening. (only if `done` was static)

Comment: I was hoping I could remove the creation of the function (or reuse functions) inside the hook rather than creating them again on each rerender thus hopefully solving the issue of the effect causing the loop. Tis a shame as the API is now pretty clunky but at least it works. Thanks very much for your time and your help.

Comment: You're welcome. Sorry that isn't exactly what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Updated Example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-dust-fvxsl

Check if(!loaded){.... setTimeout
or 
useEffect with [loaded]);

```
useEffect(() => {
    const delay = Math.random() * 1000;

    const timer = setTimeout(() => {
      setLoaded(true);
      const i = done();
      console.log("rendering multiple times", i, new Date());
    }, delay);

    return () => clearTimeout(timer);
  }, [loaded]);

  return <div>{loaded ? children : "loading"}</div>;
};
```

Comment: Thanks, I suggested this solution in my question. Whilst it works, it adds complexity and friction to the API which I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: This fixes it because of removing the dependancy on `done` which is also in my question and also breaks the linting rules as done is used in the useEffect callback :(